# How to set Authorization Headers to NativeScript http.getFile?

Tags: http, http-headers, authorization, nativescript

NativeScript Http module has a simple and good method to download files from remote server and save them on device.

```
var filePath = fs.path.join(fs.knownFolders.documents().path, 'test.png');
http.getFile('https://httpbin.org/image/png', filePath).then(function (r) {
    // Argument (r) is File!
}, function (e) {
    // Argument (e) is Error!
});
```

But today I need to set the headers for authorization and I don't know how do it...

[NativeScript Http module documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/http)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution.

1. [Official documentation](http://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/modules/_http_.html#getfile)
2. [Other question: Cannot save file with path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36516648/cannot-save-file-with-path)